# How to Solve App has Stopped in react native

Tags: android, react-native, npm

after `yarn or npm react-native-screens` my app wont debug, it says unfortunatelly, App has stopped.

and when i did

```
react-native link react-native-screens
```

it says

> npm\react-native.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
>   disabled on this system.

My RN vers.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.61.5

Answer (score 0):

That might be due to the blocker by execution policy on windows.

1) Open powershell

2) Check the results for

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

3) Set unrestricted

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since you are using React Native Version 0.60 > you don't need to link packages using command react-native link. Do not do that :) React will automatically link packages**

This is a powershell security policy, to fix it run the following

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

The stricter the policy, the more secure your system becomes.

You can change RemoteSigned to other options like: `Restricted`, `AllSigned`, `RemoteSigned`, `Unrestricted`

[Source](https://tecadmin.net/powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-system/)

Comment: thank you sir for the answer, after set execution in powershell, it still app has stopped when debugged. what options i have to choose in powershell?